# Make laravel use custom column prefix

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've a column named `people_id` instead of `user_id`, so when I run my query in laravel it throws this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `questions` (`user_id`, `created_at`) values (2, 2016-10-19 07:07:33))
```

How can I make it use people_id instead of user_id, assuming name of table is 'people'

My App/User.php file

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table='people';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','age'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function questions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\questions');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the **question** model:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'people_id');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->hasMany(Questions::class, 'people_id', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the **model name**. In your case, the Question model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key.

so, you should change to

```
return $this->hasMany('App\questions', 'people_id');
```

Maybe you should read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships